# How to refer to file with no extension in Windows?

Tags: windows, bookmarks, extension

So I have a scheduled task that's supposed to call the Chrome bookmarks file and copy it to a backup location. However, it's been failing because Task Scheduler can't recognize the location because the bookmarks file doesn't have an extension.

The file in question is:
"C:\Users[my user name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"

That path was taken by Shift+right-click on the file and choosing "Copy as path," so that's exactly how Windows sees the file. I also changed directories to that folder in Command Prompt and used the dir command to verify that as well.

(There's also a "Bookmarks.bak" file in that same folder, but I'd rather not use that one for the scheduled task since it's the previous version of the bookmarks.)

Does anyone know how to refer to that file in a way that Command Prompt can recognize it? (The scheduled task runs "cmd" to do the copy.) Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: What's the actual command your task runs? Are you running the task as your user?

Comment: I think your conclusion, thatt he cause of the problem is a missing extension, is inaccurate.  I think you're encountering a different problem.  I haven't made Bookmarks in Chrome, but the following worked for me: `C:\temp>copy "C:\Users\(myUserName)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\README" C:\temp\.` or (I just tested both of these) I could use: `C:\temp>copy "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\README" C:\temp\.`